# How to delete the second highest salary from a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete the second highest salary of an employee from a table but I am not able to find out the correct answer.

```
delete FROM user 
where salary =(select max(salary) from user where salary<(select max(salary) from user));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the subquery inside another one:

```
delete FROM user 
where salary = (select t.sal from (
    select max(salary) sal from user where salary < (select max(salary) from user)
  ) t
);
```